# Why iPad Music app says "No Content" and I cannot download music to it

Tags: itunes, music, ipad

Firstly, I have been using iPad for a few days and this things may be very nooby for you. But funny, I cannot find similar info on Apple forum.

Namely, look at this image. This is how my Music app looks like when I open it.

[image]

I was offered to download iTunes U app, which I did, but I cannot seem to find music in it, only video lectures. Next I tried going to AppStore app to Music section, but there I found only apps.

Is this app maybe limited to some countries so I cannot use it? If not, what noobish mistake I have been doing?

EDIT

There is iTunes Store app on my iPad but it looks weird. all I have is a link to use iTunes U. Check it

[image]

I searched for the term "music" but it lists podcasts from iTunes U app only.

Answer (score 1):

The iTunes Store is separate from the App Store - it should have its own icon

this is from an iPhone but they should look similar…

[image]

As you discovered, iTunesU is for education - see https://www.apple.com/education/ipad/itunes-u/

Comment: Thanks. I have that app indeed, but acts weird as well. Check my edit.

Comment: Your app Music I see on the snapshots have music inside?

Comment: yes, but only because I put music in there ;) Forget iTunesU, that's for other things entirely, only the pink/purple iTunes Store is what you need to get music

Comment: Yes, but when I open it I see the screen as in the 2nd image I attached. Check my edit. Is this weird?